# Difference between update servers

Tags: server, updates, 14.10, system-settings

If you go into the "Software & Updates" in "System Settings", it gives you the option for the "Main Server" or "Server for ***your country***" ("***your country***" replaced by the name of your country), what is the difference between those? What would be the pros and cons of using either?

I am using Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By selecting a country, you're effectively selecting a mirror server to download your software packages from. This affects the following:

- spreading the load among multiple servers instead of just one
- generating less international network traffic which is expensive (not directly for you but for other parties involved in transmissions)
- lowers network latency
- maybe higher throughput - that really depends on a server

I don't think there are CONS that you should be concerned about. Availability, redundancy of a mirror could differ between one another, meaning that mirror X could have a higher availability percentage than mirror Y but it's not that much of a time-sensitive service.