# W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, software-center, update-manager

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to run the command:

`sudo apt-get update`

and I'm getting the error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have chosen "Main Server" for source list.

Comment: Have you tried choosing the server for your country? Because it could just be an issue with the main server.

Comment: Yes I have, the servers for my country work fine, but isn't the best to choose the main servers ?

Comment: No, it is actually better to use your country's one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your country's server is working fine at the moment then you should switch to that for it is effectively a mirror server to download your software packages from. As stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572500/difference-between-update-servers) this affects:

> - spreading the load among multiple servers instead of just one
> - generating less international network traffic which is expensive (not directly for you but for other parties involved in transmissions)
> - lowers network latency
> - maybe higher throughput - that really depends on a server
>
> I don't think there are CONS that you should be concerned about.
>   Availability, redundancy of a mirror could differ between one another,
>   meaning that mirror X could have a higher availability percentage than
>   mirror Y but it's not that much of a time-sensitive service.

So if your country's server works for you, but not the main server, then use your country's one. Although there is a delay with local country servers, so the main one does get software updates faster, although if currently you are not able to get anything from it, then I think that the country ones for now are best for you until the main server is back up.

Comment: Understood, thank you, but one more question,  does the softwares on the Main Ubuntu servers are getting updates faster ?

Comment: @Benny: There is a delay with local country servers, so the main one does get software updates faster, although if currently you are not able to get anything from it, then I think that the country ones for now are best for you until the main server is back up.

Comment: And how exactly does one find and switch to their country's mirror? some of us have not read Debian/Ubuntu's source code in their spare time you know...

Comment: @matt The accepted answer fully answered the OP's question. Just look over the existing answers and if none of them work for you, [just ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and refer back to this question and explain what went wrong.  **;-)**